# Show processed images in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to display an image matrix variable on Google Colab, I have a function to change the BGR image to Grayscale, but if I display it using the function `plt.imgshow()` from `matplotlib` the image that comes out is not grayscale. I try to use the "image" function `Image` in `IPython.display` but the results don't come out, below is the script that I made

```
!wget "https://www.duckietown.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/duckietown_nice-1024x683.jpg" -O dt.jpg

import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image

image = cv2.imread('./dt.jpg')

H, W = image.shape[:2]
gray = np.zeros((H, W), np.uint8)
for i in range(H):
  for j in range(W):
    gray[i, j] = np.clip(0.299 * image[i, j, 0] + 0.587 * image[i, j, 1] + 0.114 * image[i, j, 2], 0, 255)
imgGray = gray
Image(imgGray)
```

How do I fix this? is there a function that can display images on Google Colab besides the two functions above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this. It'll show image in grayscale.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image

image = cv2.imread('./dt.jpg')
val = np.subtract(image,128)
plt.imshow(np.abs(val), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'),vmin=0,vmax=255)
plt.title('Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: yes this is a gray image, but I have to be able to show a gray image based on a process that I made myself, I'm prohibited from changing the image to gray instantly

edit : i can't use instanst converter library

Comment: `def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
 image = cv2.imread('dt.jpg')

 plt.imshow(rgb2gray(image))`